# Ruby on Rails 5 with CarrierWave cant update profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

i have a problem. I have application runnin on Ruby on Rails 5.1.1 and everythin were working til I implemented CarrierWave for upload avatars. I can create new users even if i upload an avatar, but I cant edit them anymore. It only says :

```
    --- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  _method: patch
  authenticity_token: K84njKcdK71yXXcOwlJbsvVnP00aCfj3cEMw7YuzOlbdAvjX9B14vtdpEAizJdVlv82Ngecc3my+Pz3kds44zQ==
  user: !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
    parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      username: testytests
      remove_avatar: '0'
      email: testytest@test.test
      password: ''
    permitted: false
  commit: Update account
  controller: users
  action: update
  id: '8'
permitted: false
```

if i dont change avatar and if I try to do, it says this:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"vUYySJP+yZLH7BcuckyfKdjlJIbVrFUgXRbKvu0bnVNveYXuz+8+rvX1HwFNgzvLQ1nfdIFQ7LbbjeMtw5TgFQ==", "user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"testytests", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f20ca57e8a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170525-11664-103uakm.png>, @original_filename="ruby.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"ruby.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "remove_avatar"=>"0", "email"=>"testytest@test.test", "password"=>""} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Update account", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"8"} permitted: false>
```

My users_controller.rb :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_action :find_user_by_username, only: [:new]
    before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    def new
            @user = User.new
    end

    def create
            @user = User.new(user_params)
            if @user.save
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            flash[:success] = "Vítej #{@user.username}"
            redirect_to root_path
            else
            render 'new'
            end
    end
    def edit
    end
    def update
            if @user.update(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "Profil byl aktualizovan!"
            redirect_to root_path
            else
            render 'edit'
            end
    end
    def show
            @taxi_records = @user.taxirecords.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    end
    def index
            @user = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    end

     private
    def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remove_avatar)

    end
    def set_user
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def find_user_by_username
            @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    end
    def require_same_user
            if current_user != @user
                    flash[:danger] = "Upravovat muzete pouze svuj ucet!"
                    redirect_to root_path
            end

    end
```

and user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
        has_many :taxirecords
        validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25 }
        validates :password, presence: true
        VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
        validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 105 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
        before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
        has_secure_password
end
```

I think its something with permit params but idk. I would be glad for any help or just navigation to some solution. Im stuck on this for 2 days and i dont know how to solve it. Many thanks!

EDIT: 
avatar_uploader.rb

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


   version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
   end

   def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end
```

Comment: Can you post your AvatarUploader file.

Comment: If it is a problem with your paramaters not being permitted try changing your user_params in your cotroller to params.require(:user).permit! which should whitelist all params

Comment: @HardDeveloper posted

Comment: @Mark I think its not an optimal way, but I can try
EDIT: so I did as u said and permit all params but still the same behaviour. Strange... So its not related with permit params... :(

Comment: EDIT: if statement if @user.update(user_params) cant be passed. It only render 'new' in else statement... but why?

Comment: So, Ive figured out the problem. Password was empty... Thank you all for your patience and help and Im sorry for that noobie mistake...